# submit responsive website app to google

Tags: android, responsive-design, google-play

I know that a developer can submit a native app to google. However, can I build my site responsive, have it mobile friendly and look like an app and submit the site to google play as an app with an icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap it in a WebView and compile it as an Android Application. You can read about it here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html

From a very basic standpoint, there's not a lot of work that needs to be done to get your app to open the site.